# Is Ra's Al Ghul alive or dead?

Tags: character, the-dark-knight-rises, batman-begins

Viewers are lead to believe that Ra's Al Ghul died when the train de-railed and crashed into Wayne Tower in Batman Begins.

But he appears to Bruce while he is in the pit during the Dark Knight Rises.

> **Ra's Al Ghul**: "Did you not think I would return Bruce?"
>
> **Bruce Wayne**: "Ra's?"
>
> **Ra's Al Ghul**: "I told you I was immortal."
>
> **Bruce Wayne**: "I watched, I watched you die."
>
> **Ra's Al Ghul**: "Oh there are many forms of immortality."

Is it just Bruce dreaming or is Ra's truly immortal and did appear to Bruce in the pit?

Comment: Ra's Al Ghul lives on through his daughter. Bruce's mind was quite prescient when it imagined him saying, "there are many forms of immortality"!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The fact that Ra's disappeared after talking with Bruce leads you to strongly believe that he was nothing more than a hallucination.

Keep in mind a couple of things:

1. Bruce had just undergone serious physical trauma (getting his broken back reset);
2. Ra's had figured out how to use a lotus flower to cause a person to see a blurred view of the world (think of the scene in Batman Begins when Bruce has to pick out Ra's among a group of masked assassins). In this world, its conceivable that Ra's managed to implant some suggestion in Bruce's mind that would trigger under such conditions.

**Major Spolier Alert for TDKR**

> In the end, both Talia and Bane effectively confirm that Ra's was killed by Batman in the first film, so it's pretty safe to assume that the Ra's in this film was just a hallucination.

Answer (score 3):

It is just a devise to show Bruce's detective skills. As much as it is a hallucination, it is still Bruce's problem solving. Notice that the hallucination doesn't get every detail accurately. It's because Bruce has it right that it is Rah's' legacy returning, but the hallucination doesn't correct him when he says Bane is his "heir".